# How to execute a function only when closing the selector, framework7?

Tags: jquery, html-framework-7

In this way the picker is executed in an input

```
var displayValuesProductoNuevo = ["Ninguno", "Equipo con producto","Equipo con muestra"]

    $$('#equipo_socio_nuevo').on('click', function (e) {
        let pickerSingleValue = myApp.picker({
            input: '#equipo_socio_nuevo',
            onClose: function (picker) {
                console.log(picker.value[0]);
                let  nuevo_equiposocionuevo = parseInt(picker.value[0]);
                    $('.catalogos_disponibles > tr').remove();
                    pedidoProforma(idPedido, tipo_envio, cod_agencia, cod_depto, producto_gratis,nuevo_equiposocionuevo, cod_cliente);

            },
            formatValue: function (p, values, displayValues) {
                return displayValues[0];
            },
            cols: [{
                textAlign: 'center',
                values: [0, 1,1],
                displayValues: displayValuesProductoNuevo,
            }],
        });
        pickerSingleValue.open();
    });
```

The detail I have is to use onClose because this function is executed every time the picker is opened and every time I close the picker. The picker is displayed as follows.
[image]

So the idea is that when the user selects any of those 3 options and closes the picker, execute the function.

Comment: are you looking for this: 
on: {
closed: function (picker) {
                console.log(picker.value[0]);
                let  nuevo_equiposocionuevo = parseInt(picker.value[0]);
                    $('.catalogos_disponibles > tr').remove();
                    pedidoProforma(idPedido, tipo_envio, cod_agencia, cod_depto, producto_gratis,nuevo_equiposocionuevo, cod_cliente);

            },
}

Comment: I do not have the function or should you implement my code?.  Thank you

Comment: mm, can you check this url plz: https://framework7.io/docs/picker.html - go to Picker With Single Value....you will see how F7 implement the picker, also you can implement event by this: var picker = app.picker.create({
  ...
  on: {
    closed: function () {
      console.log('Picker Closed')
    }
  }
})...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to catch the on closed event and retrieve the current picker value:

```
    self.workOrderCategoriesPicker = app.picker.create({
        inputEl: '#new-work-order-categories',
        formatValue: function(values, displayValues) {
            return displayValues;
        },
        cols: [
            {
                textAlign: 'center',
                values: id_category_list,
                displayValues: category_list,

            }
        ],
        on: {
            closed: function (picker) {
                var value = picker.value[0];
                if (value) {
                    app.dialog.alert('picker value: ' + value)
                }
            }
        }
    });
```